# Python-MySQL : How do you share or reuse single variable on 2 different function in Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have 2 different functions which makes queries and inserts datas into 2 different MySQL tables respectively. How do I reuse variable (convert) in the second function ?

```
def getRows():
    convert = str(rows)

def getDetails():
    productId = convert
```

Comment: Return it from 1st and pass as arg to 2nd?

Comment: @IljaEverilä  could you show me how ?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
#function call

converty = getRows()
getDetails(converty)



def getRows():
    convert = str(rows)
    return convert

def getDetails(convert):
    data = aliexpress.get_product_details(['productUrl', 'discount', 'evaluateScore',
                                      'volume', 'packageType', 'lotNum', 'validTime', 'storeName', 'storeUrl','allImageUrls'], convert)
    productId = convert
```

Comment: Made the edit. I hope this clarifies how the value is passed.

Comment: Please show how to pass variable convert into 2 new variables (data & productId)

Comment: what is the use of converty ?

Comment: @ReezalAQ you should really read a tutorial on how to use python functions. This is fundamental to virtually every bit of code you're going to write. It's also not exclusive to MySQL at all.

Comment: @ReezalAQ This link might help you a bit to understand functions in python: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm